# Banshee stops autoplaying, I must manually click on the song to play

Tags: 12.04, banshee, flac

When I use banshee I usually shuffle my library of music ~3000 songs mostly in flac. Sometimes it reaches a song and stops playing, it has the song lined up but never plays. I have to manually double click on the song to make it play and everything continues. It won't work if I use the play/pause keyboard shortcut either so it's a bit annoying.

I've run it in debug mode and there are not warnings and errors. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have gapless playback enabled? Try disabling it, that worked for me.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/917035

paul